# Display time using moment.js only if not 00:00:00

Tags: javascript, momentjs

How do I display the time using moment.js only if not 00:00:00?  The following works, however, seems like a bit of a kludge.  Thanks

```
function convertDate(d) {
    var l=d.length;
    var f='DD/MM/YYYY'+((l==19 && d.substr(l - 8)=='00:00:00' )?'':', h:mm:ss a');
    return moment(d).format(f);
}
console.log(convertDate("2014-11-02 02:04:05"));
console.log(convertDate("2014-11-02 00:00:00"));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use below function to get the format

```
var getDate = function(d)
{
     var format = "DD/MM/YYYY h:mm:ss a";
    if(moment(d).startOf('day').valueOf() === moment(d).valueOf())
    {
      format = "DD/MM/YYYY"
    }
    return moment(d).format(format);
}

console.log(getDate("2014-11-02 02:04:05"));
console.log(getDate("2014-11-02 00:00:00"));
```

it compare the ticks from start of day to the input time, if both are same, it means the time is zero.

Comment: as the function name suggest, it just returns the format.. not the date :)

Comment: Yes, but the `valueOf` is always the same.  If I console.log just `date.startOf('day')`, the object is different, but not the returned valueOf???

Comment: This also works: http://jsfiddle.net/ne397q4q/2/  Very odd??? Thanks for your help!

Comment: `startOf` evidently modifies the object.

Answer (score 3):

You could parse the date with moment and then use different formats according to hours/minutes/seconds values.

```
var date = moment(d);
var result;
if (date.hours() == 0 && date.minutes() == 0 && date.seconds() == 0) {
    // format without hours/minutes/seconds
    result = date.format('DD/MM/YYYY');
}
else {
    // complete format
    result = date.format('DD/MM/YYYY, h:mm:ss a'); // or whatever it is
}
```

[Documentation for getters/setters use.](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/)